# When making a class inherit `list` in Python, how can I get an instance of that list?

Tags: python, list, inheritance, instance

I'm trying to write a heap structure, and I realized most of what I was implementing in terms of indexing and setting items was already implemented in the form of `list`. How do I get an instance of that list so I can use it for the heap building?

This is about as far as I got

```py
class heap(list):
    def __init__(self, arr=None, key=None):
        super().__init__(arr)
        self._arr = arr
```

I want `self._arr` to be the instance of the list created on the line directly above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `heap` doesn't *have* a `list`, it *is* a `list`. As such, you don't access the list through an instance attribute, the instance *is* the list.

Depending on what you want to do with the list, you should operate directly on `self`.

Comment: *facepalm* I should have tried that. Thanks!! Can't accept your answer yet but I will when the timer is up.